# exclude underscore from alpha numeric regex

Tags: regex

I want use `\w` regex for to allow alpha numeric but I don't want underscore `_` to be part of it. Since `_` is included in `\w`. So I have coded like this but doesn't work, what is my mistake?

```
(/^roger\w{2,3}[0-9a-z]/i)
```

I am expecting any character other than A-Z or 1-2 to be exclude

ex -
`roger3_2 or roger46_ or roger2_`

but

> roger54 or roger4a or roger455 or rogerAAA

are to be ok

Comment: How doesn't it work? Please give more detail.

Comment: You should probably add input and expected output...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- A numeric code point is `\pN` or `\p{Number}`.
- A digit code point is `\d`, `\p{digit}`, `\p{Nd}`, `\p{Decimal_Number}`, or `\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal}`.
- An alphabetic code point is `\p{alpha}` or `\p{Alphabetic}`.  It includes all `\p{Digit}`, `\p{Letter}`, and `\p{Letter_Number}` code points, as well as certain `\p{Mark}` and `\p{Symbol}` code points.
- A programming-word code point is `\w`, or `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Digit}\p{Mark}\p{Connector_Punctuation}]`.

An alphanumeric code point by the strictest definition is consequently and necessarily `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Number}]`, typically abbreviated `[\p{alpha}\pN]`.

Answer (score 44):

You could try something like:

```
[^_\W]+
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the identifier must begin with an alpha character, and then may contain any number of alpha or numeric, I would do this:

```
my $string = 'roger54a';
print "Match\n" if $string =~ m/\A\p{alpha}[\p{alpha}\p{Number}]*\z/;
```

That anchors to the start and end of the string, precluding any characters that don't match the specific set of a single alpha followed by any quantity of alpha and numerics.

Update: I see tchrist just gave a great explanation of the Unicode properties.  This answer provides the context of a full regexp.

If you wanted the leading 'alphas' to be two or three digits followed by alpha-numeric, just add the appropriate quantifier:

`$string =~ m/\A\p{alpha}{2,3}[\p{alpha}\p{Number}]*\z/`

Update2: I see a stronger definition of what you're looking for in a comment to one of the answers here.  Here's my take on it after seeing your clarification:

`m/\Aroger[\p{alpha}\p{Number}]{2,3}\z/`

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed solution:

```
(/^roger\w{2,3}[0-9a-z]/i)
```

Means:

`\w{2,3}` -- 2 or 3 alphanumeric, including the _

`[0-9a-z]` (with the /i) -- a single character that is alphanumeric, not including the _

I didn't see any mention of the acceptable 3 alphanumerics at the beginning.  Does that belong?

Both "roger54" and "roger4a" should fail this because the above regex requires at least three characters following "roger."  Likewise, "roger_**a" would succeed because "_**" passes \w{2,3} (specifically \w{3}).

Your request sounded like you wanted more of one of these:

```
/^roger[0-9a-z]+/i
/^roger[0-9a-z]*/i
```

that is, "roger" (case insensitive) followed by one or more (+) or zero or more (*) letters and/or numbers.

Comment: you nail down my question,\w{2,3} I assume 2 or 3 alpha-numeric will be ok after roger. your solution is ok but I want allowed only 2 or 3 alpha numeric not more not less. how I can limit that. as I said my code work just fine but it's allowed (_) so I don't want that be allowed.

Comment: ahh..I got you ../^roger[0-9a-z]{2,3}/i work. thank you so very much!!

Comment: I missed the part about only 2 or 3 alphanumerics following "roger."  I'm glad you got it.  By the way, I was assuming you were doing Perl.  I'm no longer sure, but it sure looks like Perl.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a solution to this also and this solution did not work for me in C# when trying to do a regex replace. In case someone else is searching:

[c# Regex.Replace [^\w ] that also removes underscores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593723/c-sharp-regex-replace-w-that-also-removes-underscores)

This is what I use in C#:

`cleaned_string = Regex.Replace(input_string, @"[_]+|[^\w]+]", "");`

If you want to keep spaces:

`cleaned_string = Regex.Replace(input_string, @"[_]+|[^\w\s]+", "");`