# c# Regex.Replace [^\w ] that also removes underscores?

Tags: c#, regex

So I have spent far too long on this and have tried tons of things with no luck. I think I am just bad at regex. I am trying to clean a string of ALL non alpha numeric characters but leaving spaces. I DO NOT WANT TO USE `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+` due language concerns.

Here are a few things I have tried:

`cleaned_string = Regex.Replace(input_string, @"[^\w ]+[_]+);`

`cleaned_string = Regex.Replace(input_string, ([^\w ]+)([_]+));`

`cleaned_string = Regex.Replace(input_string, [^ \w?<!_]+);`

Edit: Solved thanks to a very helpful person below.

My final product ended up being this: `[_]+|[^\w\s]+`

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think you just need to escape the underscore `[^\w\_]`

Comment: None of your examples compile. What are "language concerns"? What is your example input/output?

Comment: @stephen.vakil `\_` was one of the first things I tried and it caused an exception.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I prefer \w incase the input is not just English

Comment: Ah, doesn't need to be escaped I guess.  `"[\\W_]"` seems to work locally for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you

```
// Expression: _|[^\w\d ]
cleaned_string = Regex.Replace(input_string, @"/_|[^\w\d ]", "");
```

Comment: This works perfect. I was just missing `|` in the expression it seems. Please vote this up since some tool likes to down vote.

Comment: No prob regex can cause me a head ach sometimes as well!

Comment: I also noticed that I do not need `\d` as it works with just `\w`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\W_-[\s]]+", string.Empty);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5CW_-%5B%5Cs%5D%5D&i=Some-string%3Ahere%20and_more!).

Look at `\W` pattern: it matches any non-word chars. Now, you want to exclude a whitespace matching pattern from `\W` - use [**character class subtraction**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html): `[\W-[\s]]`. This matches any char `\W` matches *except* what `\s` matches. And to also match a `_`, just add it to the character class. Add `+` quantifier to remove whole consecutive chunks of matching chars at one go.

**Details**

- `[` - start of a character class

  - `\W_` - any non-word or `_` chars
  - `-[\s]` - except for chars matched with `\s` (whitespace) pattern
- `]` - end of the character class
- `+` - one or more times.

Comment: Nice, I swapped to the `\s` in my code but kept it mostly the same. Nice info!!