# Regex lookaheads exclude underscore in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Can't work out how to exclude underscores, (password) requirement is 6 or more characters, at least one upper and lower case character, and at least one number.

It's failing on `gWT9kU4h_4`, ie it should reject this

Any ideas?

`^(?=\w{6,}$)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=[^\W_]+)`

I'm not a regex expert nor familiar with lookaheads so the above is what I put together based on my limited knowledge and from http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: Change the first lookahead to `(?=[^\W_]{6,}$)` https://regex101.com/r/TTg3ng/1

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew I saw that question and its answers, but as I said in my post, I'm not an expert in regex so how do you expect me to use other answers to solve my own problem with a more complicated problem like this?

Comment: Can anyone other than Wiktor Stribiżew perhaps explain to me why my question should have been closed and marked as duplicate?

Comment: It is marked as a duplicate as in the linked question Bogdan's answer is what you need, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9910399/11329890 for yourself. `\w` matches letters, digits and underscores, thus, you must exclude it somehow.

Comment: Ok but without being an expert in regex how should one know to change the first lookahead to what The fourth bird suggested, based on the answers in stackoverflow.com/a/9910399/11329890? One can see from my question that I had already tried something from that link in the last lookahead